# gson for generics list with list of generic elements

Tags: java, json, list, generics, gson

I have a custom list of generics which will have a bunch of generic elements. I am trying to use gson. Here are the classes:

```
public class List<E> {
    private ListElement<E> head;
    private ListElement<E> tail;
    private elementCount;
}

public class ListElement<E> {
    E element;
    private ListElement<E> prev;
    private ListElement<E> next;
}
```

and the classes are used like this

```
public class AAA {
    String x;
}

public class BBB extends AAA {
    String y;
}

public class CCC {
    String z;
    private List<BBB> listOfBBB;
}
```

When I call the "toJson" function for CCC, GSON goes into an infinite loop and crashes. I am assuming this is because of the circular reference in ListElement. Further, the List and ListElement should be serialized in particular way (noted below).

I read a bunch of the answers on this site - lots of discussion about custom GSON serialization/deserialization. I also reviewed the GSON documentation, similar recommendations. However, this particular case is not covered or at least it wasn't obvious how I might be able to solve this issue.

So I started to create custom serialization for List. Ideally the GSON serialization for List should first print the elementCount then iterate through the list elements and serialize just the "element". The head/tail should NOT be serialized as they have a meaning only at run time.

But I don't know the type of "E" at the List level. So I thought I'd add a helper function in ListElement. However, even in the ListElement class I don't the type of the element.

How can I create the custom serializer for this situation? Am I forced to create the custom serializer only for the classes where I know the type, i.e., at CCC or BBB? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: ListElement is referring to ListElement which causes this. same thing if you try to serialize an exception. Not sure if a good answer tho

Comment: That's correct, that's why I have to create a custom serializer.

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (including sample JSON)? If you can I can probably help resolve this. GSON has no problem with classes that contain fields of the same type, and similarly shouldn't have an issue with resolving `E` to `BBB` (or whatever type it should be). At least with the snippets you've provided I see no need to use a custom deserializer.

Comment: As an aside, naming a class `List` is an easy source of bugs, since it will often collide with `java.util.List`.